# Is it possible to cluster standard errors on time variables?

Tags: panel-data, clustered-standard-errors

Somewhat weird question: But is it theoretically possible to have panel data (many i, many t) where standard errors are clustered on t?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

For example, this is standard stuff in event history and growth curve models, where data are hierarchically structured with *times* of observation nested within *individuals* (or some other unit), nested within groups, nested within... etc. One can (assuming appropriate sample sizes and study design) have predictors at any level of such a hierarchy, and can decompose variance (e.g. random intercepts, random slopes, random effects) at any level of such a hierarchy. One can even have different temporal levels, such as, say days of observation at the lowest level as just described, but study years at the top of the data hierarchy. Any decent textbook on longitudinal data analysis will spell these kinds of structures out.

Comment: Thanks, interesting stuff. So if you have, let's say, daily data on temperature for different areas, does it make sense to then say, "I adjust standard errors for clusters in days"?

Comment: When you are in the realm of multilevel data structures and mixed models, I would say that one of two conditions obtains (1) you are *substantively interested* in variance, or as you suggest (2) you are are interested in estimating standard errors while accounting for the hierarchical structure of the data.

Comment: "At any level of hierarchy" is the key piece of this answer. It's important to realize that models for panel data are a very particular kind of hierarchical model.